# angular-strap modal directive not showing content twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I can't get the angular-strap modal directive to work properly. The content only shows up once, after that I just get the {{angular-expression-here}}. The original link, from the angular-strap page - does not work either. You can only see the "Hello Modal" the first time. If you want to see the message again you have to change it (eg: "Hello Modal 1").

This happens if you use the "with $http service" button.

The plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrAKPVM195vXQIC12d5J?p=preview)

Comment: I would also be happy with another alternative for this. I really just need a confirmation yes/no) dialog (angularjs and if possible bootstrap-themed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/158).

Adding **persist:true** to the modal config worked for me.

```
var modal = $modal({
        template: 'partials/main/modal.html',
        show: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        scope: $scope,
        persist: true
    });
```